# Age based on birthday into

Tags: google-sheets

please help if you can.

In one spot of a sheet I'm trying to keep track of age in years + months (ex:10 years 8 months) in age using datif.

My biggest issue with it is making sure any cell that doesn't have a date written in leaves a blank cell where the formula is.

What I have so far, "(today) wasn't working for some reason so I just used a hidden cell on the far right as a constant"

=DATEDIF(I7,AG2,"Y")&" Years "&DATEDIF(I7,AG2,"YM")&" Months "

any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm still learning how to formula in general :-D

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula in cell `J7`

```
=index(if(I7:I,datedif(I7:I,today(),"Y") &" Years "& datedif(I7:I,today(),"YM") &" Months ",))
```

this does not calculate when a cell in `column I` is empty, but will calculate all cells in that column that contain a `valid date`. (no need for dragging down)

The `today()` function works perfectly and keeps the age calculation updated.